# Shinyproxy is taking over 30 seconds to start an application

Tags: r, shiny, shinyproxy

R-shiny Application loads pretty quickly if run locally but seems to take an inordinate amount of time to load when run through shinyproxy. I have tried tweaking the heartbeat and load-wait times, and springboot although slow doesn't seem to account for all the delay, I'm running centos7 with the latest shinyproxy rpm install. Docker has been configured correctly (the containers do start eventually).

The shiny logs don't give much detail other than starting docker and proxy enabled.

Has anyone come across an issue similar to this before? Is this normal?

Comment: You might want to ask this at the support forum https://support.openanalytics.eu/

Answer (score 1):

I think it is normal due that shinyproxy needs to start a docker service for every user that log on your app.